# Ruby on Rails 5, tabbed template

Tags: css, templates, tabs, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to figure out how I can implement a tabbed site similar to the image below.  Does anyone know/recognize this template or can guide me on how I can design something similar with bootstrap and css?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap has a javascript tab plugin included to change tabs on clicking. You can checkout https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navs/#javascript-behavior

If you want the pages to load a new page on clicking you could do something like (I've used font awesome for the icons here)

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" href="/sourcing"><i class="fa fa-pie-chart"></i>Sourcing</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="/people"><i class="fa fa-user-o"></i>People</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

In bootstrap 4 this would get the basic example working and you could play around with the CSS to change the look of each a when it has the "active" class